# Trying to perform an insert into

Tags: mysql

Been trying to perform an insert into command for a table called customers. However whenever I try to do a query I get the following error.

Error Code: 1364. Field 'customer_address' doesn't have a default value 0.000 sec

I'm not entirely sure how I would go about setting a default value. Any suggestions?

```
lock table customers write;

set foreign_key_checks = 0;

alter table customers modify customer_id integer auto_increment;

insert into  customers (customer_first_name, customer_last_name)
values ("Nathan", "Rivera"),
        ("thom", "something");
```

Here is the script used to create my table

```
-- *************************************************************

-- This script creates the database

-- **REVISED by PRP to remove some orders
-- **REVISED by PRP to add artist table
-- **REVISED by PRP to link employee table to orders
-- *************************************************************



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_details;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS artists;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees;

-- create tables

CREATE TABLE customers

(

customer_id           INT          ,

customer_first_name   VARCHAR(20),

customer_last_name    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,

customer_address      VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,

customer_city         VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,

customer_state        CHAR(2)         NOT NULL,

customer_zip          CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,

customer_phone        CHAR(10)     NOT NULL,

customer_fax          CHAR(10),

CONSTRAINT customers_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)

);



CREATE TABLE artists

(

artist_id           INT             NOT NULL,

artist_name   VARCHAR(30),

CONSTRAINT artist_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (artist_id)

);


CREATE TABLE items

(

item_id       INT             NOT NULL,

title         VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,

artist_id     INT     NOT NULL,

unit_price    DECIMAL(9,2)    NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT items_pk 
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id),

CONSTRAINT items_fk_artists
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artists (artist_id)
);





CREATE TABLE employees

(

employee_id         INT               NOT NULL,

last_name           VARCHAR(20)       NOT NULL,

first_name          VARCHAR(20)       NOT NULL,

manager_id          INT
,
CONSTRAINT employees_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
CONSTRAINT emp_fk_mgr FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees(employee_id) );

CREATE TABLE orders

(

order_id          INT         NOT NULL,

customer_id       INT         NOT NULL,

order_date        DATE        NOT NULL,

shipped_date      DATE,

employee_id       INT,

CONSTRAINT orders_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id),

CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customers
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
CONSTRAINT orders_fk_employees
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id)

);



CREATE TABLE order_details

(

order_id      INT           NOT NULL,

item_id       INT           NOT NULL,

order_qty     INT           NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT order_details_pk 
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id, item_id),

CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_orders
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
    REFERENCES orders (order_id),

CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_items
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
    REFERENCES items (item_id)

);




-- insert rows into tables

INSERT INTO customers VALUES 

(1,'Korah','Blanca','1555 W Lane Ave','Columbus','OH','43221','6145554435','6145553928'), 

(2,'Yash','Randall','11 E Rancho Madera Rd','Madison','WI','53707','2095551205','2095552262'), 

(3,'Johnathon','Millerton','60 Madison Ave','New York','NY','10010','2125554800',NULL), 

(4,'Mikayla','Davis','2021 K Street Nw','Washington','DC','20006','2025555561',NULL), 

(5,'Kendall','Mayte','4775 E Miami River Rd','Cleves','OH','45002','5135553043',NULL), 

(6,'Kaitlin','Hostlery','3250 Spring Grove Ave','Cincinnati','OH','45225','8005551957','8005552826'), 

(7,'Derek','Chaddick','9022 E Merchant Wy','Fairfield','IA','52556','5155556130',NULL), 

(8,'Deborah','Davis','415 E Olive Ave','Fresno','CA','93728','5595558060',NULL), 

(9,'Karina','Lacy','882 W Easton Wy','Los Angeles','CA','90084','8005557000',NULL), 

(10,'Kurt','Nickalus','28210 N Avenue Stanford','Valencia','CA','91355','8055550584','055556689'), 

(11,'Kelsey','Eulalia','7833 N Ridge Rd','Sacramento','CA','95887','2095557500','2095551302'), 

(12,'Anders','Rohansen','12345 E 67th Ave NW','Takoma Park','MD','24512','3385556772',NULL), 

(13,'Thalia','Neftaly','2508 W Shaw Ave','Fresno','CA','93711','5595556245',NULL), 

(14,'Gonzalo','Keeton','12 Daniel Road','Fairfield','NJ','07004','2015559742',NULL), 

(15,'Ania','Irvin','1099 N Farcourt St','Orange','CA','92807','7145559000',NULL), 

(16,'Dakota','Baylee','1033 N Sycamore Ave.','Los Angeles','CA','90038','2135554322',NULL), 

(17,'Samuel','Jacobsen','3433 E Widget Ave','Palo Alto','CA','92711','4155553434',NULL), 

(18,'Justin','Javen','828 S Broadway','Tarrytown','NY','10591','8005550037',NULL), 

(19,'Kyle','Marissa','789 E Mercy Ave','Phoenix','AZ','85038','9475553900',NULL), 

(20,'Erick','Kaleigh','Five Lakepointe Plaza, Ste 500','Charlotte','NC','28217','7045553500',NULL), 

(21,'Marvin','Quintin','2677 Industrial Circle Dr','Columbus','OH','43260','6145558600','6145557580'), 

(22,'Rashad','Holbrooke','3467 W Shaw Ave #103','Fresno','CA','93711','5595558625','5595558495'), 

(23,'Trisha','Anum','627 Aviation Way','Manhatttan Beach','CA','90266','3105552732',NULL), 

(24,'Julian','Carson','372 San Quentin','San Francisco','CA','94161','6175550700',NULL), 

(25,'Kirsten','Story','2401 Wisconsin Ave NW','Washington','DC','20559','2065559115',NULL);




INSERT INTO artists(artist_id,artist_name) VALUES 

(10, 'Umani'),
(11, 'The Ubernerds'),
(12, 'No Rest For The Weary'),
(13, 'Burt Ruggles'),
(14, 'Sewed the Vest Pocket'),
(15, 'Jess & Odie'),
(16, 'Onn & Onn');


INSERT INTO items (item_id,title,artist_id,unit_price) VALUES 

(1,'Umami In Concert',10,17.95),

(2,'Race Car Sounds',11,13),

(3,'No Rest For The Weary',12,16.95),

(4,'More Songs About Structures and Comestibles',12,17.95),

(5,'On The Road With Burt Ruggles',13,17.5),

(6,'No Fixed Address',14,16.95),

(7,'Rude Noises',15,13),

(8,'Burt Ruggles: An Intimate Portrait',13,17.95),

(9,'Zone Out With Umami',10,16.95),

(10,'Etcetera',16,17);

INSERT INTO employees VALUES 

(1,'Smith',    'Cindy', null),

(2,'Jones',    'Elmer', 1),

(3,'Simonian', 'Ralph', 2),
(9,'Locario',  'Paulo',1),
(8,'Leary', 'Rhea',9),
(4,'Hernandez','Olivia',9),

(5,'Aaronsen', 'Robert',4),

(6,'Watson',   'Denise',8),

(7,'Hardy',    'Thomas',2);



INSERT INTO orders VALUES

(19, 1, '2012-10-23', '2012-10-28', 6),

(29, 8, '2012-11-05', '2012-11-11', 6),

(32, 11, '2012-11-10', '2012-11-13', NULL),

(45, 2, '2012-11-25', '2012-11-30', NULL),

(70, 10, '2012-12-28', '2013-01-07', 5),

(89, 22, '2013-01-20', '2013-01-22', 7),

(97, 20, '2013-01-29', '2013-02-02', 5),

(118, 3, '2013-02-24', '2013-02-28', 7),

(144, 17, '2013-03-21', '2013-03-29', NULL),

(158, 9, '2013-04-04', '2013-04-20', NULL),

(165, 14, '2013-04-11', '2013-04-13', NULL),

(180, 24, '2013-04-25', '2013-05-30', NULL),

(231, 15, '2013-06-14', '2013-06-22', NULL),

(242, 23, '2013-06-24', '2013-07-06', 3),

(264, 9, '2013-07-15', '2013-07-18', 6),

(298, 18, '2013-08-18', '2013-09-22', 3),

(321, 2, '2013-09-09', '2013-10-05', 6),

(381, 7, '2013-11-08', '2013-11-16', 7),
(413, 17, '2013-12-05', '2014-01-11', 7),

(442, 5, '2013-12-28', '2014-01-03', 5),

(479, 1, '2014-01-30', '2014-03-03', 3),

(491, 16, '2014-02-08', '2014-02-14', 5),


(523, 3, '2014-03-07', '2014-03-15', 3),

(548, 2, '2014-03-22', '2014-04-18', NULL),

(550, 17, '2014-03-23', '2014-04-03', NULL),

(601, 16, '2014-04-21', '2014-04-27', NULL),

(607, 20, '2014-04-25', '2014-05-04', NULL),

(624, 2, '2014-05-04', '2014-05-09', NULL),

(627, 17, '2014-05-05', '2014-05-10', NULL),

(630, 20, '2014-05-08', '2014-05-18', 7),

(651, 12, '2014-05-19', '2014-06-02', 7),

(658, 12, '2014-05-23', '2014-06-02', 7),

(687, 17, '2014-06-05', '2014-06-08', NULL),

(693, 9, '2014-06-07', '2014-06-19', NULL),

(703, 19, '2014-06-12', '2014-06-19', 7),

(778, 13, '2014-07-12', '2014-07-21', 7),

(796, 17, '2014-07-19', '2014-07-26', 5),

(800, 19, '2014-07-21', '2014-07-28', NULL),

(802, 2, '2014-07-21', '2014-07-31', NULL),

(824, 1, '2014-08-01', NULL, NULL),

(827, 18, '2014-08-02', NULL, NULL),

(829, 9, '2014-08-02', NULL, NULL);




INSERT INTO order_details VALUES 

(381,1,1),(601,9,1),
(442,1,1),
(523,9,1),

(630,5,1),
(778,1,1),
(693,10,1),
(118,1,1),

(264,7,1),
(607,10,1),
(624,7,1),
(658,1,1),

(800,5,1),
(158,3,1),
(321,10,1),
(687,6,1),

(827,6,1),
(144,3,1),

(479,1,2),

(630,6,2),(796,5,1),(97,4,1),
(601,5,1),

(800,1,1),
(29,10,1),
(70,1,1),


(165,4,1),
(180,4,1),
(231,10,1),


(413,10,1),
(491,6,1),

(607,3,1),
(651,3,1),
(703,4,1),


(802,3,1),
(824,7,2),

(829,1,1),
(550,4,1),
(796,7,1),
(693,6,1),
(29,3,1),
(32,7,1),
(242,1,1),

(298,1,1),
(479,4,1),
(548,9,1),
(627,9,1),

(778,3,1),

(19,5,1),
(89,4,1),

(242,6,1),
(264,4,1),
(550,1,1),


(693,7,3),
(824,3,1),
(829,5,1),
(829,9,1);
```

Comment: Show us the table definition, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error Code: 1364. Field 'customer_address' doesn't have a default value 0.000 sec

That means that the customer_address column is set to NOT allow NULL values and that no default value has been specified. Therefore your insert statement *must* include the customer address field.

```
insert into  customers (customer_first_name, customer_last_name, customer_address)
values ("Nathan", "Rivera", "1000 Fred St."),
    ("thom", "something", "9659 Foobar Dr.");
```

Now that you've added your table defs it's clear that you'll need the other fields that you've marked *NOT NULL* as well in the insert statement, or you'll see a similar error for each one you leave out.

Comment: Okay now im trying to edit the table to make it default and or nullable I tried using alter table customers
modify customer_first_name varchar default; however it gives me a syntax error that default is not at a valid position. I have also tried alter table customers
alter column customer_first_name varchar null; Id like to avoid going back and changing all the null values and adding default to them if I can help it.

Comment: Figured it out, I used alter table customers modify customer_first_name varchar(20) null;

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a default value using the `DEFAULT` option in the `CREATE TABLE` query.

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
customer_id           INT,
customer_first_name   VARCHAR(20),
customer_last_name    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
customer_address      VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
customer_city         VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
customer_state        CHAR(2)         NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
customer_zip          CHAR(5)     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
customer_phone        CHAR(10)     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
customer_fax          CHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT customers_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

Comment: Doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose of `NOT NULL`?